# Adding node webkit app as plugin

Tags: node-webkit

I have a web-kit app, can any one please help in integrating this web-kit app along  with  Google chrome browser or is there any other possible way in which I can interrelate this  App with a browser?

Comment: Do you want to have chrome extension communicating with running node-webkit app? Do you want chrome extension to start/stop nw app? or just exchange some data?

Comment: I want to add nw app as plugin to chrome